# TFS2013 Checkin Notification: Can I change context on files before checking in

Tags: tfs, checkin

I'm making a check in Notification where I need to change the files before checking them in and Merge on TFS server 2013.

So I think if I could download the data stream on the server, make the changes and then upload them to TFS.

Do any of you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, and actually TFS is working in this way.

To edit version controlled files, you need to get the files on local machine (workspace), modify the content of these files and check in. Then the check-in notification is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I want is when I check in the notification has to strip my xml programmatically. So I want to download the file on the server before it is checked in